# Show that two 3d surfaces generally intersect in a curve (trying to prove this, I am getting paradoxical results)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I came across the following problem in Synge and Schild’s Tensor Calculus (page 6, just before the beginning of subunit 1.2), and in working on it I arrived at a paradoxical result (namely, that two surfaces in three dimensional space can only intersect in a finite number of points). The problem states:

Let $U_{2}$ and $W_{2}$ be two subspaces of $V_{N}$. Show that, if N=3, $U_{2}$ and $W_{2}$ will in general intersect in a curve.

[Edit: Before my attempt at a solution, let me state some definitions from the book:

- We call a set of values $x^1, x^2, ..., x^N$ a *point*
- The totality of points corresponding to all values of the coordinates within certain ranges constitute a *space of N dimensions*, which is referred to by a symbol such as $V_{N}$
- The totality of points given by the equations
  $$x^{r} = f^{r}(u) \hspace{20pt} (r = 1, 2, ..., N)$$
  is called a *curve*
- The totality of points given by
  $$ x^{r} = f^{r} (u^{1}, u^{2}, ..., u^{M}) \hspace{20pt} (r=1, 2, ..., N)$$
  where M<N, is called a *subspace* of $V_{N}$. If $M = N-1$ ,the subspace is called a *surface*.]

Below is my attempt at a solution:

Let the subspaces U and W be defined by the equations

U:
$$X^1 = f^{1}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$
$$X^2 = f^{2}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$
$$X^3 = f^{3}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$
W:
$$X^1 = g^{1}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$
$$X^2 = g^{2}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$
$$X^3 = g^{3}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$

At their points of intersection, it must hold true that

1. $$f^{1}(u^{1}, u^{2}) = g^{1}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$ AND
2. $$f^{2}(u^{1}, u^{2}) = g^{2}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$ AND
3. $$f^{3}(u^{1}, u^{2}) = g^{3}(u^{1}, u^{2})$$

Equation 1 will give us $u^{2}$ as an implicit function of $u^{1}$; let’s call that function $u^{2a}(u^{1})$. Equations 2 and 3 will also give us $u^{2}$ as an implicit function of $u^{1}$; let’s call these functions $u^{2b}(u^{1})$ and $u^{2c}(u^{1})$ respectively. Then, since equations 1, 2, and 3 should simultaneously hold true at points of intersection, U and W only intersect at the points for which

$u^{1}$ is such that $u^{2a}(u^{1}) = u^{2b}(u^{1}) = u^{2c}(u^{1})$

$u^2 = u^{2a}(u^{1}) = u^{2b}(u^{1}) = u^{2c}(u^{1})$, where $u^{1}$ has the value(s) we found above

and, in the general case, there will exist only a finite number of such points, or no such points at all.

I know that the result I arrived at is false. Where in my reasoning have I made a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand any of your notation. Can you add definitions?

Comment: In English, "subspace" is the wrong word. I assume you're talking about submanifolds? Your overall mistake is that you're assuming that the parametrizations use the same variables. Change the second set of $(u^1,u^2)$ to $(v^1,v^2)$. If you know the implicit function theorem, it might be easier to represent these surfaces locally as graphs $X^3 = f(X^1,X^2)$ and $X^3=g(X^1,X^2)$.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger Thank you for your comment, I added some definitions from the book where the problem is from.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your response. I understand that changing the second set of $(u^1, u^2)$ to $(v^1, v^2)$ would prevent my paradoxical result from emerging. I also understand how representing the surfaces as $X^3 = f(X^1, X^2)$ and $X^3 = g(X^1, X^2)$ makes it easier to solve the exercise (thank you for this hint). However, I do not understand why it is wrong to assume that the two parameterizations use the same set of variables. Do you have any further reading suggestions that might help me understand why using $(u^1, u^2)$ in both parameterizations is wrong? ty in advance

Comment: Let’s try an easier example. Find the intersection of the lines given parametrically by $x=0$, $y=t+1$ and by $x=t$, $y=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin (1/2) This was SUCH an enlightening example. I see that, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the first line you mentioned is the y axis, and the second line is the x axis, and these axes have a unique intersection point, namely the origin. But if I were to employ my false method, I would require $t = 0$ AND $t + 1 = 0$ to hold true at the intersection points, and thus come to the false conclusion that the two lines do not intersect.

Comment: @TedShifrin  (2/2) I now understand that it is possible for two parametrically defined curves to intersect at a point even if each curve “passes” through the intersection point for different values of the parameter, and, by the same token, that two surfaces may intersect at some point(s) even if each surface “passes” through the intersection points for different values of the parameters $(u^1, u^2)$. I now understand where my mistake lay, thank you so much for answering my question :)

Comment: You're welcome. Why don't you write up a short official answer to the question?